# Netty channelRead0 not firing

Tags: netty

I've never worked with Netty before and I created a Netty server. When I send something to it, channelRead0 never gets fired; only channelRead. Why is that and how can I trigger it? I'm using netty version 4.0.12. Thanks!

Server :

```
void run() {

    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 100)
                .childHandler(new UTFServerInitializer());

        ChannelFuture f = b.bind(this.port).sync();
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }

}
```

Initializer Handler :

```
static class UTFServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {

        ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();

        pipeline.addLast("UTFHandler", new UTFServerHandler());
    }

}
```

Call Handler :

```
static class UTFServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext arg0, Object arg1)
            throws Exception {

        ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) arg1;

        try {
            while (in.isReadable()) {
                System.out.print((char) in.readByte());
                System.out.flush();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext arg0, String arg1)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // not fired
        System.out.println("channelRead0");

    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx)
            throws Exception {
        super.channelReadComplete(ctx);
        System.out.println("channelReadComplete");

    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause)
            throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put all your business logic inside the channelRead0 method and **remove** the channelRead method. In this case, the channelRead0 will be called by default.

Answer (score 4):

You override the channelRead method. In SimpleChannelInboundHandler, there is a template method which invokes your channelRead0 implementation.

```java
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    boolean release = true;
    try {
        if (acceptInboundMessage(msg)) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            I imsg = (I) msg;
            channelRead0(ctx, imsg);
        } else {
            release = false;
            ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
        }
    } finally {
        if (autoRelease && release) {
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

SimpleChannelInboundHandler intercepts certain type of message dedicated by your typeName, for example `SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Integer>` intercepts Integer. And you need to add a StringDecoder to pipeline before this handler to convert ByteBuf to String.